# How to get Image matrix of an image using libjpeg

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing, libjpeg

Does any function in libjpeg outputs an image matrix just like imread does in matlab?

Answer (score 4):

From the libjpeg v9 release notes (http://www.ijg.org/files/):

> Pixels are stored by scanlines, with each scanline running from left to
>   right.  The component values for each pixel are adjacent in the row; for
>   example, R,G,B,R,G,B,R,G,B,... for 24-bit RGB color.  Each scanline is an
>   array of data type JSAMPLE --- which is typically "unsigned char", unless
>   you've changed jmorecfg.h.  (You can also change the RGB pixel layout, say
>   to B,G,R order, by modifying jmorecfg.h.  But see the restrictions listed in
>   that file before doing so.)
>
> A 2-D array of pixels is formed by making a list of pointers to the
>   starts of scanlines; so the scanlines need not be physically adjacent
>   in memory.  Even if you process just one scanline at a time, you must
>   make a one-element pointer array to conform to this structure. 
>   Pointers to JSAMPLE rows are of type JSAMPROW, and the pointer to the
>   pointer array is of type JSAMPARRAY.
>
> The library accepts or supplies one or more complete scanlines per
>   call. It is not possible to process part of a row at a time. 
>   Scanlines are always processed top-to-bottom.  You can process an
>   entire image in one call if you have it all in memory, but usually
>   it's simplest to process one scanline at a time.

The key section is:

> A 2-D array of pixels is formed by making a list of pointers

This means that library does not natively return a "matrix" of pixels; rather, it returns rows (scanlines), and the user is responsible for arranging those scanlines into a "matrix".  This is not too challenging, but a bit of work is needed.  The following code snippet shows a working example of JPEG decompression:

```
while (decompressor.output_scanline < decompressor.output_height)
{
    pRow = &jpegInputBuffer[decompressor.output_scanline*rowStride];
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&decompressor, &pRow, 1);
}
```

Note that I've omitted a number of details (definition of *pRow*, *rowStride*, how the *decompressor* struct is loaded, etc) because those seem to be beyond the scope of the question.